# Join dataframes including mutual pairs

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I want to join two dataframes by two columns they have in common but I do not want mutual pairs to be considered as duplicates.

Sample dataframes look like:

```
>df
letter1 letter2 value
 d       e     1
 c       d     2
 c       e     4

>dc
letter1 letter2
 a       e
 c       a
 c       d
 c       e
 d       a
 d       c
 d       e
 e       a
```

I want to join them by the first two columns, leaving in the third column the value in df$value and NA if the row does not exist in df. I have tried:

```
s <- join(dc,df, by = c("letter1","letter2"))

>s
letter1 letter2 value
a        e       NA
c        a       NA
c        d       2
c        e       4
d        a       NA
d        c       2
d        e       1
e        a       NA
```

Here, the pair `d c` is considered the same as `c d` and the value in the third column is the same. What I want is `d c` being considered as non-present in df, so their row value is NA. My desired output is:

```
>s
letter1 letter2 value
a        e       NA
c        a       NA
c        d       2
c        e       4
d        a       NA
d        c       NA
d        e       1
e        a       NA
```

How can I join the dataframes so mutual pairs are considered different combinations?

**UPDATE: I am sorry but I have just realized there was a problem with my input dataframes and that the join line I was trying actually works. I will accept the first answer that also works to give credit to the author.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge` instead of `join`:

```
merge(dc,df, by = c("letter1","letter2"),all=TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry for my earlier comment, you're right. Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` to change the order

```
 df[1:2] <- t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort))
 dc <- t(apply(dc, 1, sort)
```

and then do the `join`

Answer (score 0):

```
#Creating the data frames
df <- data.frame(letter1=c("d","c","c"),
                 letter2=c("e","d","e"),
                 value=c(1,2,4))

dc <- data.frame(letter1=c("a","c","c","c","d","d","d","e"),
                 letter2=c("e","a","d","e","a","c","e","a"))

# Merging the data frames
dout <- merge(df,dc,by=c("letter1","letter2"),all=T)

# Outcome
letter1 letter2 value
1       c       d     2
2       c       e     4
3       c       a    NA
4       d       e     1
5       d       a    NA
6       d       c    NA
7       a       e    NA
8       e       a    NA
```